# Porting a React app to Vite and hosting inside ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, vite

I have an ASP.NET Core (.NET 7.0) that reverse proxies to an SPA. It works with Angular and React, but not with Vite.

- Working (React):

  ```cs
  app.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
          spa.Options.SourcePath = "react/fact-find";

          if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
          {
              spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
          }
          else
          {
              app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
          }
      });
  ```

  and

  ```json
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  ```
- Not working (Vite):

  ```cs
  app.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
      spa.Options.SourcePath = "vite/fact-find";

      if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
      {
          spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start"); // https://github.com/martijnboland/LeanAspNetCore-React/blob/main/ClientApp/package.json
          spa.Options.DevServerPort = 3000;
      }
      else
      {
          app.UseSpaStaticFiles(); // TODO: check that it works.
      }
  });
  ```

  and

  ```json
  "start": "echo Starting the development server && vite --host localhost --port 3000"
  ```

In the Vite case I get the ASP.NET error page with

```
HttpRequestException: Failed to proxy the request to http://localhost:57034/, because the request to the proxy target failed. Check that the proxy target server is running and accepting requests to http://localhost:57034/. The underlying exception message was 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:57034)'.
```

where `57034` is a different random port every time I start the application.

What's going on? Why does ASP.NET have completely different behaviour in the Vite case? What is generating random port numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be that

```
spa.Options.DevServerPort = 3000;
```

must go *before*

```
spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
```

Possilbly related:

- delete the `dist` folder, and
- switch to a different `launchSetting.json` and back.